# How do I configure the MVN POM files for provided library in distributable assembly for different submodules

Tags: maven, dependencies, git-submodules, maven-assembly-plugin

after searching through all the related posts, I was still unable to find an answer to my exact problem, so I hope someone here can help me out.

What I have is a project with 3 modules, where 2 modules use the same 'base'module. eacht module must be deployed to a different server with different provided libraries.

It looks like this:

```
Project
 |
 -- Modules
    |
    -- Module Base
    |
    -- Module A
    |
    -- Module B

pom file of Project has dependency managment where library 1 is declared with version 1.0
pom file of Module Base has dependency on library 1.
pom file of Module A has dependency on Module Base.
pom file of Module B has dependency on Module Base.

Module A is deployed on a server X where library 1 is provided.
Module B is deployed on a server Y where library 1 is NOT provided.

On server X the size of Module A must be kept as small as possible, so library 1 cannot end up in the distributable of Module A.
```

How should I configure the pom files to get everything build and running correctly?

I tried a whole bunch of possibilities already but am unable to get it correct so that the assembly of A does not have library 1 present, and the assembly of B does have library 1 present.

All help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Best would be having an example project which shows the real structure and what you have tried so far...

Comment: I created a test project, but how do I share this here? I have it as a zip file but you cannot attach anything to the post as far as I can see.

Comment: Create an example project on github / bitbucket etc. ?

Comment: My apologies @khmarbaise, I'm pretty new to this, I normally only work on the closed alreay existing projects of my company and never have to create new projects. But I got the test project on bitbucket. If I give you the following line is that then enough for you to retrieve the project? bitbucket.org/rubenvanstraten/testmvnmoduledependency.git

Answer (score 0):

Well it very much depends on what in reality depends on what. What you've declared in the POMs may or may not represent the reality. As I don't know that, I'll just give you the options you have:

---

**Option 1**

Move the dependency on `library 1` from `Module Base` to `Module A`. Since you expect `module B` to be able to work with `Module Base` but without `library 1` it probably means that `Module Base` does not really need `library 1`

**Option 2**

If the above is not the case and `Module Base` does need `library 1` sometimes but can work without it other times - you should make the dependency optional. Then you can add it to `Module A` and not add it to `Module B`

**Option 3**

In the weird case when `library 1` is not optional for `Module Base` but you happen to somehow know that `Module B` does not touch code from `Module Base` that needs the library - exclude the dependency on `library 1` when you define the dependency on `Module Base` in `Module B`

---

For more information about both option 2 and 3 please have a look at "[optional and excludes dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)" docs.

**UPDATE:**

After the clarifying comment it appears that `library 1` is needed by all modules and the difference is only whether or not it is provided at runtime. In that case, you need to copy the dependency from `Module Base` to `Module A` and change the [dependency scope](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) to `provided` for `Module A`. That way, assuming your packaging mechanism understands Maven scopes,  `Module B` will be using the `compile` scope via `Module Base` and so `library 1` will be added to the final package while `Module A` will know it's provided and should not have it in the package.

Comment: Milen, thank you for your answer, let me reply to that.
None of the options are a solution.
The fact is that the library on server X is already deployed and in the classpath, and may not be in the distributable of Module A.
On server Y, this library is not deployed and also cannot be deployed, so it needs to be part of the distributable of Module B.

I hope this makes is clear.

Comment: Milen,

I think my packaging mechanism doesn't fully recognize the maven scopes. It didn't work. I now just hard excluded the library in the assembly.xml file as a last resort. That seems to do the trick.